# Solutions of triangles, homework

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have 2 questions in which I have doubt :-

Q1. prove that:- a cosBcosC + b cosAcosC + c cosBcosA = ar(ABC)/R

A1. I have used cosine rule and have put the values of all cosines here and after adding them, this is what I get:-
 
LHS=  [1/abc]* $[2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2+2a^2b^2-($a^4+b^4 +c^4$)]$

I can't go ahead:(.

Q2. If D is the midpoint of CA in triangle, then show that:-

tan(angleADB)=4*ar(ABC)/$(a^2-c^2)$

A2. AD=b/2

 BD=1/2*square root of$(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)$

BE=2*ar(ABC)/b

 ED=some complex term which I am unable to solve.

 diagram:- http://prntscr.com/1v8psh
[dia http://prntscr.com/1v8psh](http://prntscr.com/1v8psh)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $ABC$ in the first line?

Comment: ar(ABC)= area of triangle ABC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first use $a=b\cos C+c\cos B$ to get

$$a\cos B\cos C+b\cos C\cos A+c\cos A\cos B=a\cos B\cos C+\cos A(b\cos C+c\cos B)$$

$$=a\cos B\cos C+a\cos A=a\{\cos B\cos C+\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})\}$$

$$=a\{\cos B\cos C-\cos(B+C)\}\text{ as }\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$$

$$=a\{\cos B\cos C-\cos B\cos C+\sin B\sin C)\}$$

$$=a\sin B\sin C$$

But from the [sine law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)  $a=2R\sin A$ etc. and we know $\displaystyle\triangle =\frac{abc}{4R}$

---

For the second, using [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines),

in 
$\displaystyle \triangle CDB, a^2=BD^2+\left(\frac b2\right)^2-2BD\cdot \frac b2\cos\angle CDB$
$\displaystyle a^2=BD^2+\left(\frac b2\right)^2-2BD\cdot \frac b2\cos(\pi-\angle ADB)$

$\displaystyle\implies a^2=BD^2+\left(\frac b2\right)^2+2BD\cdot \frac b2\cos\angle ADB \ \ \  \ \ (1)$ as $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$

in 
$\displaystyle \triangle ADB, c^2=BD^2+\left(\frac b2\right)^2-2BD\cdot \frac b2\cos\angle ADB\ \ \ \ (2)$

$\displaystyle(1)-(2)\implies a^2-c^2=2BD\cdot b\cos\angle ADB\ \ \ \ (3)$

Now we need to eliminate $BD$ from $(3)$

So, applying sine law in $\displaystyle \triangle ADB,$ we get $\displaystyle\frac{BD}{\sin A}=\frac c{\sin\angle ADB}$

Putting the value of $BD$ is $\displaystyle(3), a^2-c^2=2\frac{c\sin A}{\sin\angle ADB}\cdot b\cos\angle ADB$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{\sin\angle ADB}{\cos\angle ADB}=\frac{2bc\sin A}{a^2-c^2}=\frac\triangle{a^2-c^2}$

Comment: so it will become 2RsinAsinBsinC, what to do next?

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: @gaurav, so we have $$a\sin B\sin C=a\cdot\frac b{2R}\cdot\frac c{2R}=\frac1r\frac{abc}{4R}$$

Comment: oh yes sorry, and thanks:)

Comment: and can you help me in the second one also?

Comment: @gaurav, I have added the second solution

Comment: thanks a lot, can you give me your email ID so that I can contact you for any other doubts?